# Вернуть объект после SELECT запроса

Tags: java, sql

Верно ли такое решение, для того, чтобы вернуть объект после SELECT запроса? Если нет, то прошу помочь, как лучше реализовать.

```
public Object selectValue() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet resultSet = super.executeSqlValue("SELECT c.id,c.name FROM class_rooms AS c " +
            "INNER JOIN pupils_in_class_rooms AS in ON c.id = in.idClassRooms");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString("name"));
        System.out.println(classRoom.getName());
    }
    return resultSet.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить один объект, то надо делать так:

```
// Либо вернется объект ClassRoom, либо null, если такой записи в таблице нет
public ClassRoom selectValue() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet resultSet = super.executeSqlValue("SELECT c.id,c.name FROM class_rooms AS c " +
            "INNER JOIN pupils_in_class_rooms AS in ON c.id = in.idClassRooms");
    ClassRoom classRoom = null;
    if (resultSet.next()) { // if, а не while
        classRoom = new ClassRoom(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString("name"));
        System.out.println(classRoom.getName());
    }
    return classRoom;
}
```

А если много, то так:

```
// возвращаем массив комнат
public List<ClassRoom> selectValue() throws SQLException {
    ResultSet resultSet = super.executeSqlValue("SELECT c.id,c.name FROM class_rooms AS c " +
            "INNER JOIN pupils_in_class_rooms AS in ON c.id = in.idClassRooms");
    List<ClassRoom> rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        classRoom = new ClassRoom(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString("name"));
        rooms.add(classRoom);
        System.out.println(classRoom.getName());
    }
    return rooms;
}
```

Comment: У меня есть еще вопрос, он маленький, не понимаю, как в гугле сформировать запрос. У меня есть функция insert она по сути одна и таже, только принимает разные объекты, в одном случае Pupil, в другом случае Teacher и тд, как это грамотно реализовать? Я делаю implement интерфейса и получаю этот метод универсальный, который во всех классах сработает.

Comment: @Saintka насколько я понял вам надо сделать немного по-другому. Создайте метод, принимающий параметр ID объекта, параметры для непосредственно INSERT, а также название таблицы в которую вы этот инсер делаете. Тем самым вы получите один вид запроса для разных объектов. Но! Лучше так не делать, потому что вы не знаете, что понадобится  инсертить в будущем (какие параметры) для того, или другого объекта. Лучше иметь разные инсерты для разных объектов, а когда перейдете на ORM вообще будет все равно :)

Comment: Хорошо, понял, спасибо)